# #MYSQL query to multiply resultant fields

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT *,   
           CASE 
             WHEN(max(`priod_id`) > 4) THEN 
               "0.2" 
             ELSE 
               "0.25" 
           END AS PERCENTAGE,   
           COUNT(priod_id) as HOURS,
           COUNT(CASE 
                   WHEN nota_id = '1' THEN 
                     1 
                 END) AS PR
      FROM `attendance_tbl` A 
     WHERE DATE(attend_date) BETWEEN DATE('2018-08-01') AND DATE('2018-08-31') 
       AND sid = '60' 
  GROUP BY DATE(attend_date)
```

We need to multiply PERCENTAGE and PR
(PERCENTAGE * PR) AS TOTAL
Please tell us a technique to resolve the query.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/52365860/2469308

Comment: Recently tried Query.SELECT *,PERCENTAGE,PR,(PERCENTAGE * PR) as Total 
FROM (SELECT *,
CASE WHEN(max(`priod_id`) > 4) THEN "0.2" ELSE "0.25" END AS PERCENTAGE,
count(priod_id) as HOURS,
COUNT(CASE WHEN nota_id='1' THEN 1 END) AS PR,
FROM attendance_tbl WHERE DATE(attend_date) BETWEEN DATE('2018-08-01') AND DATE('2018-08-31')  and sid = '60' GROUP BY DATE(attend_date)) as go

Comment: What do you mean ? @AyyappanSri

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) from your existing `SELECT` query's result set. Afterwards, you can do various operations (eg: multiplication here), in an outer `SELECT` clause `FROM` the Derived table. Try the following:

```
SELECT inner_nest.*, 
       inner_nest.PERCENTAGE * inner_nest.PR AS TOTAL 
FROM
(
  SELECT *,   
         CASE 
           WHEN(max(`priod_id`) > 4) THEN 
             "0.2" 
           ELSE 
             "0.25" 
         END AS PERCENTAGE,   
         COUNT(priod_id) as HOURS,
         COUNT(CASE 
                 WHEN nota_id = '1' THEN 
                   1 
               END) AS PR
  FROM `attendance_tbl` A 
  WHERE DATE(attend_date) BETWEEN DATE('2018-08-01') AND DATE('2018-08-31') 
    AND sid = '60' 
  GROUP BY DATE(attend_date)
) AS inner_nest
```